# How to make ACS variables display on terminal

Tags: c++, ncurses, xterm, urxvt

Is there any way to force displaying ACS variables from ncurses in terminal?
On urxvt and text-mode everything displays well, but on other terminals (i tested on xfce4-terminal, xterm, gnome-terminal)there is always is problem. I tought I can do nothing with this, but I saw that in alsamixer everything displays properly. I loop up for this in alsamixer code and saw they are using exacly same method to display this characters, for examle

```
addch(ACS_RARROW);
```

is giving them [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5IZx.png) result while same command gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ajvf.png) on same terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a terminal where your locale says to use UTF-8 (you can see this by the naming convention of values shown by the `locale` command), you must do this:

- compile/link with *ncursesw*
- initialize the locale before `initscr`, e.g.,

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

See the [*Initialization*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) section of the ncurses manual, as well as the [*Line Graphics*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics) section of the `addch` manual page.